# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 order joined relations with QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm using Symfony2 and have a headache on ordering results by joined relations with QueryBuilder. I want to select a group by ID with ordered related items. Here's the code:

```
$rs = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('a', 'c', 'm')
    ->leftJoin('a.item', 'c', Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.active = 1')
    ->leftJoin('c.media', 'm')
    ->where('a.id = :group_id')
//  ->orderBy('c.sortOrder', 'asc')
    ->setParameter('group_id', $group_id)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

This way I get what I want, but items aren't ordered. If I uncomment line `->orderBy('c.sortOrder', 'asc')`, I get empty result set. Tried to execute runnable query in PHPMyAdmin and both (with ordering and without) queries return same results, but one is ordered as it should be.

Is there any way to get relations ordered?

Comment: Did you try debug the query produced by query builder? You can do that in this way: var_dump($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL());
var_dump($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getParameters());

Comment: I've tried `getDQL()` and both queries are the same except for `ORDER BY`. Will try tomorrow at work `getSQL()` and `getParameters()`, but I don't think I'll see something new, because `getDQL()` and runnable query for both with/out ordering are exactly the same except for `ORDER BY` and in PHPMyAdmin results are also exactly the same, except for order.

Comment: As I said - parameters are the same and both queries' difference is just `ORDER BY` part. I think I'll just go with getting group data and then retrieve ordered active items by group ID.

Comment: So, you say even the sql query don't work with "order by" ? Can you post this sql?

Comment: No - in the post I wrote _Tried to execute runnable query in PHPMyAdmin and both (with ordering and without) queries return same results, but one is ordered as it should be._
Both queries return the same result. Just order is different, but `getResult()` does not return relations at all if I use `orderBy('c.sortOrder', 'asc')`